# Abstract Jordan decomposition maybe not exist

Tags: lie-algebras

[This note](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.745/Notes/Lecture_12_Notes.pdf) defines the abstract Jordan decomposition in an arbitrary Lie algebra. Abstract Jordan decomposition in a Lie algebra is unique **when it exists** iff its centre is zero. It seems that the abstract Jordan decomposition maybe not exist even when its centre is zero, who can show me an example?

Comment: Answered at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345066/abstract-jordan-decomposition-maybe-not-exist), crossposting.